# Save state of fragments using BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bundle, state, bottomnavigationview

I'm using BottomNavigationView. I have three tabs with a form. I want to keep what user wrote in fields when he goes to another tab and then come back.
This is the Activity that contains BottomNavigationView.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@BindView(R.id.bottom_navigation)
BottomNavigationView navigation;
@BindView(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initToolbar();
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    //select first tab
    navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_expiration_key);
}

@Override
protected void initializeDagger() {
    ((MainApplication) getApplicationContext()).getAppComponent().inject(this);
}

@Override
protected void initializePresenter() {
}

@Override
public int getLayoutId() {
    return R.layout.activity_main;
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.navigation_expiration_key:
            selectedFragment = KeyExpirationFragment.newInstance();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_place_identification:
            selectedFragment = LockIdentificationFragment.newInstance();
            break;
        case R.id.navigation_bt_key:
            selectedFragment = BtKeyValidationMenuFragment.newInstance();
            break;
    }
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, selectedFragment);
    transaction.commit();
    return true;
}
```

I've tried to save state in fragments using this:

```
    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString(KEY_NUMBER, keyNumberField.getText().toString());
    savedInstanceState.putString(CUSTOMER, customerField.getText().toString());
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        String keyNumber = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_NUMBER);
        keyNumberField.setText(keyNumber);
        String customer = savedInstanceState.getString(CUSTOMER);
        customerField.setText(customer);
    }
}
```

But onSaveInstanceState is never called when going to other Tab.
I understand that we shouldn't save state of fragments when we are navigating through the app. And this is pretended to be triggered when f.e. phone rotates.

But as we save state with ViewPager, etc. There should be a way to keep these states properly. No using shared preferences, or bad fixes.

Regards.

Comment: are you using view pager?

Comment: No at all. Just all you can see.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for this answer myself.  I am not sure, as I have seen this both ways, but I do think you need your super line after the others.  Like this:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
     savedInstanceState.putString(KEY_NUMBER, keyNumberField.getText().toString());
     savedInstanceState.putString(CUSTOMER, customerField.getText().toString());
     super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

edit 2:   I am going to try fragments instead, via RayWenderlich tutorial.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/169885/android-fragments-tutorial-introduction-2